# Story or short story about a planet where the sunlight never ends

Tags: story-identification

I read the story in the 80's or 90's and the key memory I had was that as the planet's sun set, the star became like a ring of fire on the horizon until it rose on the opposite point on the horizon in the morning. Basically the sunlight never completely disappears and there is a glow around the horizon all through the night.

I seem to think that the team who land there comment that Earth is very nearly the right diameter / distance for this effect to occur. So perhaps this was from a collection of parallel or alternate Earths. Not so sure about this second paragraph but the Meta suggested any clue might help.

Comment: Just to be clear, is the ring of fire seen on the planet the observers are standing on? It isn't like an eclipse where the Moon is just the right size to exactly mask out the Sun so we see a ring of fire (the corona) around it during the eclipse?

Comment: yes - seen from the surface, so that the planet they are on is causing the annular eclipse effect / corona effect. I think it was more like the corona as you suggest, the star definitely 'set' but light was visible along the horizon

Comment: So it's definitely not Asimov's classic *Nightfall*. Oh well. ;)

Comment: What would cause the effect? A weird high-density atmosphere? But not _Mesklin_... Extreme gravitational lensing? But not _Dragon's Egg_...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this happens on Venus in the 1975 John Varley story "[In the Bowl](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?50783)".

> Then there's the sun. When I was there it was nighttime, which means
> that the sun was a squashed ellipse hanging just above the horizon in
> the east, where it had set weeks and weeks ago. Don't ask me to
> explain it. All I know is that the sun never sets on Venus. Never, no
> matter where you are. It just gets flatter and flatter and wider and
> wider until it oozes around to the north or south, depending on where
> you are, becoming a flat, bright line of light until it begins pulling
> itself back together in the west, where it's going to rise in a few
> weeks.
>
> Ember says that at the equator it becomes a complete circle for a
> split second when it's actually directly underfoot. Like the lights of
> a terrific stadium. All this happens up at the rim of the bowl you're
> standing in, about ten degrees above the theoretical horizon. It's
> another refraction effect.

Don't ask me to explain it either.

Comment: Thank you so much for that ! Sounds like it could be it.  Have been googling that story at apparently it appeared in an anthology called "Not the Only Planet" and that is ringing some faint memory bells.

Comment: Have re-read the story and think this the one, although the story is not about this per se its just one of the events that occur and must have stuck in my mind. Thanks for helping!